# Statistical models for dependency of responses?

Tags: correlation, multivariate-analysis, modeling, covariance

What are some ways I can model the dependency or correlation of my responses?

**The data:**

How many hours does the patient spend doing X?

How many hours does the patient spend doing Y?

How many hours does the patient spend doing Z?

**The question:**

I have little interest in the actual levels of the hours.

We are more interested in the following question: when the patient spends more time doing $X$, does that happen at the expense of $Y$? Or $Z$? Or does $Y$ and $Z$ increase with $X$? Or are they more or less independent?

And how does that dependency change (if at all) given some covariates? For example we might have a factor like "gender", and then we want to see if women and men have different correlations.

Any model or literature recommendations?

Comment: Are $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ exhaustive, or is there other time-use unaccounted-for?